# Make choice from array semi-randomly based on string

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, hash

I have this problem. I'd like to make random a choice from array `[1,2,3,4]` based on arbitrary 6 letter string in such way that this choice is always same if string is same.

So if i have string 'dogdog' function would return always `'3'` for example, but `'4'` for 'bigcat' etc.

I think the solution might be first hashing the string. How could one convert hash string into choice from array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate a hash from a string and take the array item at `[hash % array.length]`. An example with the DJB hashfunc  (see http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html for more):

```js
function djbHash(s) {
    let hash = 5381;

    for (let c of s) {
        hash = hash * 33 + c.charCodeAt(0);
    }
    return hash;
}

function mapToValues(s, values) {
    return values[djbHash(s) % values.length];
}

console.log(mapToValues('dogdog', [1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(mapToValues('bigcat', [1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Comment: This is a good solution because the hashing function have a good distribution. Better hashing functions give better results!

Answer (score 0):

A really simple hash function:

- Change each letter of your word by a number (a is 1, b is 2, etc.). Let's call **w** the whole word changed in a number.
- Calculate **i** = **w** mod 4. **i** will be a number between 0 and 3. Add 1 to it.
- Congrats, you can now associate any word to a "random" number between 1 and 4. You can of course replace 4 by any other number to associate each world to a random number in any range.

Comment: Your random number algorithm gives an exceptionally poor distribution.